# Emoji support in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, encoding, emoji

I read a bunch of articles on the topic of how to implement emoji support in MySQL, but nothing does not work.

my.cnf:

```
[client]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
[mysqld]
character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
character-set-client-handshake = FALSE
[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
```

test:

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value              |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary             |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4            |
| character_set_system     | utf8               |
| collation_connection     | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server         | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+--------------------------+--------------------+
```

I've tried both MyISAM and InnoDB.

What is wrong with this?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```sql
mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------+
| VERSION() |
+-----------+
| 5.7.11    |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SET NAMES utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_test`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_test` (
    ->   `message` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL
    -> ) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO `tbl_test` (`message`)
    -> VALUES ('Hello ');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT `message`
    -> FROM `tbl_test`;
+------------+
| message    |
+------------+
| Hello      |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/dR54SPnR3iokFfDURsEmvw/0).

**UPDATE**

Using Workbench 6.3 Community:

[image: Workbench 6.3 Community]

Comment: Thank you, it works with terminal. But how can I do this with MySQL workbench or C++? Do you know?

Comment: @VladMarkushin: Updated answer.